# Java Android not writing to and reading from file properly

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with writing and reading from file as the title suggests.  As I am saving to internal storage I am not able to access the default path that my file has saved to. I have 2 hashmaps, one of which holds the current data that is to be written to the file and the other is to store data when I read in from the text file. I am doing this to check whether or not the file has been written to properly. I'm sorry if there are any initial faults with the code it will be tidied up later once I get this working, I am fairly new to working with Android and java.

`FILENAME` is a String which holds just the filename itself along with its extension which is `.txt`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    File fp = new File(context.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    if(fp.exists()){
        Log.d("FILE", "EXISTS");
    } else
        Log.d("FILE", "DOES NOT EXISTS");

    Log.d("HOME", "pause called");
    // loop until entries are written to file   
    try{
        if(!dataBank.isEmpty()){
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = dataBank.entrySet().iterator();

            while(i.hasNext()){
                String key = i.next().getKey();
                Log.d("WRITE", key + "," + dataBank.get(key));
                out.write(key + "," + dataBank.get(key) + "\n");
            }

            out.close();
            fos.close();
        }

        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);

        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String read = "";
        Log.d("FILE0", "READ");
        while((read = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] dataArray = new String[2];
            dataArray = read.split(",");
            compare.put(dataArray[0], dataArray[1]);
        }
        bReader.close();
        fis.close();
        Log.d("FILE1", "READ");

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "onPause!");
    }
}
```

From the `Log.d` messages this is what I get. The order I entered them in are `John`, `Alice` and then `Bob`.

[image: logcat log]

I have an EditText box which is where the user types a name and 2 buttons, one button takes you to selecting an image from the gallery and from that it gets the file path and stores it in the value associated with the key which is the name typed into the textbox.  These are added during this method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        old_User = username; 
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);          
        dataBank.put(old_User, selectedImagePath);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED TO GET FILEPATH...", duration).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can i have more of your log message.

Comment: I have just posted up a picture @Learner

Comment: are you having null in your data, there are 3 records in which 1st record is null as key. can you check your data. if you have correct entry explain how you insert your data.

Comment: @Learner I have re-edited and added more to the post, hopefully it will be helpful.  I have to type name into the EditText box first before selecting an image.

Comment: how do you want the result to be.

Comment: I want the result to be how I entered it. For example John - image path, Alice - image path, Bob - image path.  Not a good example, but I know the first entry should be John and not Null.  Also when read into the second dictionary it should have the same entries as dataBank.  If that makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54002/discussion-between-learner-and-dorkmonstuh).

Answer (score 1):

If you need consistent ordering, you can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (for insertion/access order).
so you can order it.